# shared filesystem with offline access

Tags: networking, filesystems

I would like a shared filesystem with offline access. I have two machines. One is a light laptop with a small amount of SSD storage that I carry with me. The other is a stay-at-home computer with much more storage. I want to be able to mount the home directory of my stay-at-home computer onto my laptop while I'm on my home network. I also want to have access to a subset of files while offline. The solution should have the following characteristics.

1. A single consistent home directory shared between both computers
2. The ability to work on either machine
3. The directory structure of the laptop should remain visible when offline
4. All files should be available to the laptop when on the network
5. A subset of files should be available when offline
6. Ability to remove files from local storage on the laptop without removing the original

Does something like this exist? Or does someone have an idea of how to implement it?

Comment: Consider using distributed version control instead. Both Git and Mercurial also have some support for large files.

Comment: You may possibly want to look into Syncthing.